# C# join two tables and filter on a field of second table joined in the query

Tags: c#

I have an ObjectA model which has a list of ObjectB’s model as a field in it but is not a column on the table for ObjectA’s model.

I am trying to add a filter on the ObjectA’s endpoint which can return me ObjectA from the database where it matches a field on ObjectB. The field name to filter on is “id”

I have a function that returns IQueryable where I would return a query that joins these two tables and returns records that match the field “id” in the ObjectB with the passed field id.

The query that joins the table is:
 `var query = _context.ObjectA.Include(b => b.ObjectB).AsQueryable();`

the code I have that works but I think there might be better way to do this without this messy looking code.

```
 if (filterModel.id != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(i => i.ObjectB.AsQueryable().Where(o => o.id.ToString().Equals(filterModel.id)).First().id.ToString() == filterModel.id
                );
            }

            return query;
```

Comment: I've read the prose a couple of times but I still don't quite get it; can you post your tables, sample data and entities? And a more clear description of the problem, perhaps not with contrived object names. For example "one Company has many Employee. I want to get all Companies where having one or more Employee called John" (e.g. `companies.Where(c => c.Employees.Any(e => e.Name == "John"))` )

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
query = query.Where(i => i.ObjectB.Any(o => o.id.ToString().Equals(filterModel.id)));
```